# What is needed to provision a list with a ratings column? (Average rating)

Tags: 2013, javascript, xml, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to create a page library with a ratings columns. I've been able to create other columns just fine, but the ratings one is giving me issues.

```
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(appUrl);
        var web = context.get_web();

        var lci = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
        lci.set_title(listTitle);
        lci.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.webPageLibrary);

        var list = web.get_lists().add(lci);

        list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field' +
        ' Name="AverageRating"' +
        ' StaticName="AverageRating"' +
        ' DisplayName="$Resources:spscore,Ratings_AverageRatingFieldName;"' +
        ' Description="$Resources:spscore,Ratings_AverageRatingFieldDescription;"' +
        ' Group="$Resources:spscore,Ratings_FieldsGroup_15;"' +
        ' Type="AverageRating"' +
        ' Decimals="2"' +
        ' Min="0" Max="5"' +
        ' ShowInEditForm="FALSE"' +
        ' ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"' +
        ' ShowInNewForm="FALSE"' +
        ' CanToggleHidden="TRUE"' +
        ' JSLink="sp.ui.reputation.js"' +
        ' SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3">' +
           '<FieldRefs>' +
             '<FieldRef Name="RatingCount" />' +
             '<FieldRef Name="RatedBy" />' +
             '<FieldRef Name="Ratings" />' +
           '</FieldRefs>' +
        '</Field>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);            

        context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);
```

The site will build fine, but after I create a page and go back to the display page of the library I receive an error

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'trim' of undefined or null
>   reference
>
> TypeError: Unable to get property 'trim' of undefined or null
>   referenceTypeError: Unable to get property '_events' of undefined or
>   null reference

UPDATE:
So it appears that column is getting added, but there problem is that it is not displaying correctly. If I remove the column from the view then the list will load fine. When it's turned on is when I receive the error.